# C# file limit using System.IO.StreamWriter with long string Json

Tags: c#, json, arrays

I am using Json for a big array, and the result of Json is on `"sz"(string).`

When I want to save the Json result (`string sz`) on a file it will not save the whole string, why?

Note the string value is about 184985 characters.

Here is the code what i have tried so far :

```
 string sz = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(tempArray);

 using (StreamWriter file = File.AppendText("json.txt"))
 {
      file.Write(sz);
 }
```

I tried to use

```
File.AppendAllText(@"json.txt", sz);
```

And

```
System.IO.StreamWriter file = new System.IO.StreamWriter("json.txt", true);
```

The file size is just 200K.

Is there a limit in text file in windows ?

Comment: why don't you simply use `File.AppendAllText("json.txt, sz)`?

Comment: Your code works fine for me. I just edited the file path to point to my linqpad-queries folder, hit f5 and voila: the output of [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9], which was the content of my array was located in a json.txt

Comment: It's not working too, the string value is 184985 characters

Comment: A file size of 204800 bytes to store 184985 characters isn't totally unreasonable.

Comment: I take everything back. I just tried to reproduce your error with a 40Mb csv file, which I am converting to JSON. The new file is around 40kb large.

Comment: I cannot reproduce your issue. `string test = new string('A', 184985); using (var file = File.AppendText(path))
                file.Write(test);

            var test2 = File.ReadAllText(path);

            Console.Write("Test.Length:{0} Test2.Length:{1} equal:{2}",test.Length, test2.Length, test.Length==test2.Length);` Output is: `Test.Length:184985 Test2.Length:184985 equal:True` and the file-size is: `181KB`.

Comment: If your data is large, you'll want to serialize it to a stream rather than using an intermediate in-memory string. e.g. `new JsonSerializer().Serialize(File.AppendText("bla"), myArray);`. Make sure you close the stream correctly after serialization to force the final flush (unflushed writes are typically the reason for cases such as this).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- "Is there a limit in text file in windows ?"
- No (well 2GB at FAT32 system)

I'm not sure what the problem is, but I can share my snippet I use all the time, let me know if works for you.

```
public class JsonFile 
{
    public JsonFile()
    {
        formatting = Formatting.Indented;
    }

    public JsonFile(Formatting formatting)
    {
        this.formatting = formatting;
    }

    private Formatting formatting;

    public T Load<T>(string filename)
    {
        string json = File.ReadAllText(filename);
        return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(json);
    }

    public void Save(string filename, object data)
    {
        File.WriteAllText(filename, JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data, formatting), Encoding.UTF8);
    }
}
```

Comment: Using above code files, exported DB records are saved in excel as : \r\n\t\t. Could you please suggest what additional changes are required

Comment: Not sure what are you trying to do? "exported DB records are saved in excel" we are talking JSON here so not sure if Excel handles JSON? feels like you may be talking CSV here...

Answer (score 0):

"Use This Code"

```
System.IO.StreamWriter file = new System.IO.StreamWriter(@"myFile.txt");

file.AutoFlush = true;
```